# Constructing a nontrivial action of $A_{4}$ on $S$ with $|S| = 3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

This comes from Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter $0$. The the first part of the question was to prove for $n \geq 5$, show that there are no nontrivial actions of $A_{n}$ on any set $S$ with $|S| < n$. The next part was to construct a nontrivial action of $A_{4}$ on a set $S$ with $|S| = 3$.

An action of $A_{4}$ on a $3$-set is the same as a homomorphism $\varphi:A_{4} \to S_{3}$. As $|A_{4}| = 12$ and $|S_{3}| = 6$, $\varphi$ cannot be injective. $A_{4}$ contains a normal subgroup of order $4$, consisting of all permutations of type $[2,2]$ with identity, and this must be the kernel of $\varphi$ as $\varphi$ is not injective and nontrivial. By the first isomorphism theorem, the image of $\varphi$ must consist of three elements of $S_{3}$. My first thought was something like this
$$\varphi(\sigma) = \begin{cases} \text{Id}_{S_{3}} & \sigma = \text{Id}_{A_{4}}, (1 \ 2)(3 \ 4), (1 \ 3)(2 \ 4), (1 \ 4)(2 \ 3) \\ (1 \ 2 \ 3) & \sigma = (1 \ 2 \ 3), (1 \ 2 \ 4), (1 \ 3 \ 4), (2 \ 3 \ 4) \\ (1 \ 3 \ 2) & \sigma = (1 \ 3 \ 2), (1 \ 4 \ 2), (1 \ 4 \ 3), (2 \ 4 \ 3) \end{cases}$$
But this is not a homomorphism. Is there a better way at constructing such a homomorphism than guessing and checking?

Comment: Do you know that $A_4$ is the symmetry group of a tetrahedron? If so, then you can take the 6 edges and create three sets of pairs of opposite edges. Rotations act on these edge pairs.

Comment: There are two actions you might think of - the usual action on the cosets of the kernel and (here as a special case) an action on the non-identity elements of the kernel, of which there happen to be 3.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you! Now that you pointed it out, it is completely obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action $\varphi$ by left multiplication of $A_4$ on the set of the three cosets of $V_4=\{(),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}\le A_4$ is not trivial, because its kernel is:
$$\ker\varphi=\bigcap_{\sigma\in A_4}\sigma V_4\sigma^{-1}\le V_4<A_4$$

Comment: Thank you so much!